# Getting undefined value/text from drop down list using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I can't figure out why I'm getting undefined or null data when I select item from the drop down list.

```
<form action="">
  <select class="form-control regist-user-input" id="user.attributes.countryId" name="user.attributes.countryId" required>
                        <option value="">Country</option>
                            <option value="1" >
                            AFGHANISTAN
                            </option>
                            <option value="2" >
                            ALAND ISLAND
                            </option>
                            <option value="3" >
                            ALBANIA
                            </option>
                            <option value="4" >
                            ALGERIA
                            </option>
                            <option value="5" >
                            AMERICAN SAMOA
                            </option>
                            <option value="6" >
                            ANDORRA
                            </option>
                            <option value="7" >
                            ANGOLA
                            </option>
                            <option value="8" >
                            ANGUILLA
                            </option>
                            <option value="9" >
                            ANTARCTICA
                            </option>
                            <option value="10" >
                            ANTIGUA AND BARBUDA
                            </option>
                    </select>
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" onClick="myNewFunction()">
</form>

<script>
var e = document.getElementById('user.attributes.countryId');
var inpCountry = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;

function myNewFunction() {
    alert(inpCountry.text);
}
</script>
```

Both inpCountry.value and inpCountry.text when I try to alert it, get undefined data. What seemed to be the mistake here?

Comment: just remove the `.text` to your `alert(inpCountry.text);` that's all

Comment: i already tried that and i'm getting "country" but not exatly the text from my selected item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to get the element inside the function. This is because these two line

`var e = document.getElementById('user.attributes.countryId');
var inpCountry = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;`

Secondly since the `input` type is submit prevent it's default behavior of submitting the form

will not be updated on selecting the submit button

```js
function myNewFunction(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  var e = document.getElementById('user.attributes.countryId');
  var inpCountry = e.options[e.selectedIndex];
  console.log(inpCountry.innerHTML.trim());
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <select class="form-control regist-user-input" id="user.attributes.countryId" name="user.attributes.countryId" required>
    <option value="">Country</option>
    <option value="1">
      AFGHANISTAN
    </option>
    <option value="2">
      ALAND ISLAND
    </option>
    <option value="3">
      ALBANIA
    </option>
    <option value="4">
      ALGERIA
    </option>
    <option value="5">
      AMERICAN SAMOA
    </option>
    <option value="6">
      ANDORRA
    </option>
    <option value="7">
      ANGOLA
    </option>
    <option value="8">
      ANGUILLA
    </option>
    <option value="9">
      ANTARCTICA
    </option>
    <option value="10">
      ANTIGUA AND BARBUDA
    </option>
  </select>
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" onClick="myNewFunction(event)">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var inpCountry = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;

function myNewFunction() {
    alert(inpCountry.text);
}
```

should be

```
function myNewFunction() {
    var inpCountry = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text; //so that selectedIndex is checked again whenever this function runs
    alert(inpCountry.text);
}
```

Comment: still undefined

Answer (score 0):

Remove `.text` to the inpCountry.

```html
<form action="">
  <select class="form-control regist-user-input" id="user.attributes.countryId" name="user.attributes.countryId" required>
                        <option value="">Country</option>
                            <option value="1" >
                            AFGHANISTAN
                            </option>
                            <option value="2" >
                            ALAND ISLAND
                            </option>
                            <option value="3" >
                            ALBANIA
                            </option>
                            <option value="4" >
                            ALGERIA
                            </option>
                            <option value="5" >
                            AMERICAN SAMOA
                            </option>
                            <option value="6" >
                            ANDORRA
                            </option>
                            <option value="7" >
                            ANGOLA
                            </option>
                            <option value="8" >
                            ANGUILLA
                            </option>
                            <option value="9" >
                            ANTARCTICA
                            </option>
                            <option value="10" >
                            ANTIGUA AND BARBUDA
                            </option>
                    </select>
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" onClick="myNewFunction()">
</form>

<script>
var e = document.getElementById('user.attributes.countryId');
var inpCountry = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;

function myNewFunction() {
    alert(inpCountry);
}
</script>
```

Comment: i already tried that and i'm getting "country" but not exatly the text from my selected item

Answer (score 0):

i hope this will be help you

function myNewFunction() {

```
var e = document.getElementById('user.attributes.countryId');
var inpCountry = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text; 
alert(inpCountry);
}
```